# Copyright my website name. Is this possible?

Tags: copyright

I am wondering if besides owning my domain name, should I copyright the actual name of the site?

If my site is called **mysite.com**. Could I go to http://www.copyright.gov/ and copyright **mysite**?

Or do I need to do nothing? What would be best if someone was to try and steal my website name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you really want for that is more likely a trademark or servicemark.  Copyright protects the content of a given work and a URL/site name is too short to copyright.
(http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-protect.html#title explains that you cannot copyright names, titles, and slogans).

You can start here (assuming you are in the USA by your copyright.gov) link.

http://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/basics/index.jsp

Comment: Just to add, you automatically have copyright on your actual content when you publish it; there is no need to explicitly register it.